# How can I best adjust my database to record the amount of rounds per fight and the round/minute a fight ended?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm storing statistics of what time a fight was ended in, **if it ended at all**. Not all fights end and the ones that don't become decisions.

Example:

> Kitao defeated Jones via submission
>   (keylock) at 2:14 of round 1.

From this piece of data, I want to store 3 things:

1. if the fight ended, the time in which it ended
2. if the fight ended, in which round did it end

The complex part of this, however, is that because I am tracking fights from multiple organizations, not every organization had a consistent amount of minutes per round so I can't make a column for `secondsPerRound`. So it seems like I need to create a separate table that tracks all possible combinations of rounds/minutes... example a `fight_rounds_types` table:

```
id   organization_id  num_rounds
1    9                5
2    10               3
```

and a minutes_rounds mapping table?

```
id   fight_rounds__types_id  round_num  mins
1    1                       1          5
2    1                       2          5
3    1                       3          5
4    1                       4          5
5    1                       5          5
6    2                       1          10
7    2                       2          5
8    2                       3          5
```

Then with this type of `fights` table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `fights` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `winner_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `referee_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `championship_match` enum('1','0') DEFAULT '0',
  `weight_class` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `finish_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `loser_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `w` (`winner_id`),
  KEY `e` (`event_id`),
  KEY `f` (`finish_id`),
  KEY `l` (`loser_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `l` FOREIGN KEY (`loser_id`) REFERENCES `fighters` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `e` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `f` FOREIGN KEY (`finish_id`) REFERENCES `finishes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `w` FOREIGN KEY (`winner_id`) REFERENCES `fighters` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I could add a foreign key to the `fight_rounds` id, and for the things I want to track:

1. minute, if the fight ended
2. round, if the fight ended

I would make a tinyint column, `round_ended` which can be NULL, as well as a `time_ended` column, and a foreign key reference, `fight_rounds_types_id` which would reference the type of minutes/rounds rules to use.

My questions are:

1. Is my schema for `fight_rounds_types` and `minutes_rounds` ideal in regards to normalization? Or is there a better way I can design this?
2. What column type can I use for a `time_ended` column? I want to track say, `2:14`. I ended up using `TIME` for now, is that ideal?

Comment: You said, "Not all fights end." Are you sure about that?

Comment: Well, some go to a decision, by "end" I mean literally end in a way that doesn't rely on time expiring.

Answer (score 1):

I would have columns on my Fights table for TotalElapsedSeconds and SecondsPerRound. Then number of completed rounds can be calculated by dividing the former by the later. The length into the last round can be calculated by modulus of the former by the latter. A separate tables seems like overkill.

Comment: But the thing is, not every round has the same amount of time. In the `PRIDE` organization, they had a 10 minute first round and 5 minute subsequent rounds... and there's a possibility that there were some fights which had customized rules such as this... that's the monkey wrench in this whole thing...

Answer (score 0):

why not track two columns:  finish_round, and finish_seconds.

then you can fill them in appropriately no matter what system is being used.

Comment: What would be the difference vs `time_ended` and `round_ended`? Other than `finish_seconds` bringing up more work because of the extra calculation step in determining seconds when I can simply track `2:14` for example?